# url from dictionary to uiimage

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uikit, uiimage

i have an nsdictionary, named 'JsonItem' which contain object for key 'PictureURl' i.e. an url, n try to pass it to NSURL, then to NSData and further to UIImage, but it is not showing any image  in UIImage.

```
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"]]]];
```

Comment: What are you using to parse the JSON data? What do you get when you log the object for that key? What do you get when you log the object's class? If you get a URL, have you verified that that URL refers to something that exists?

Comment: @Peter Hosey: its working now!! everything is fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296002/nsdata-datawithcontentsofurl/5296014#5296014).

Comment: @hennes: No, because in that question, the questioner is passing the string where the URL is expected (as you yourself pointed out in your answer), whereas in this question, the questioner is passing a URL.

Comment: @ketan rajput: Then please post an answer explaining what the problem was and how you solved it.

Comment: @hennes: i had a problem that i was not able to pass url from NSDictionary to NSData because url contain spaces in the beginning. thats why in NSData i was receiving null. so some one suggested me to use string replacing methods. after that all is working well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `[jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"]` is a `NSString`, if its an `NSUrl` try this

```
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"]]];
```

Comment: when i get the value of '[jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"]' in   NSURL then is giving only url    json url....
    http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Images/partlycloudy.gif
2011-03-14 13:14:13.235 XML[7191:20b] json url....{
    PictureURL = "\n    http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Images/partlycloudy.gif";
}