# NSData dataWithContentsOfURL

Tags: iphone, uiimage, nsdata, nsurl

I have this method for button click (download). The problem is that it is terminating due to an exception:

```
[Session started at 2011-03-14 13:06:45 +0530.]
2011-03-14 13:06:45.710 XML[7079:20b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason: '*** -[NSCFString isFileURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x62b8'
```

```
-(IBAction) download
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:@"http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Images/thunderstorms.gif"]];
    [image release];
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Why are you releasing image? You are not allocating it.

Comment: that was by mistake !!! my url is not getting in to uiimage.      UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"]]];            error:    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFString isFileURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd552c0'

Answer (score 39):

It expects an NSURL as argument, not a string.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Images/thunderstorms.gif"]]];
```

---

EDIT:

To test if the data has loaded succesfully try something like

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:yourURL options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    [error release];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Data has loaded successfully.");
}
```

Comment: actuall in my code i am deriving url from { NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"]]; }   {NSLog(@"%@",[jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"]);} is also printing correct url but when using code  {  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:string]]];}  error is displayed (already explained)

Comment: Hm, that doesn't make sense. What is the exact error message you get after calling UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:string]]];?

Comment: when i tried this: UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"]]];      it giving error      :2011-03-14 15:19:42.119 XML[8388:20b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFString isFileURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd54bc0'
2011-03-14 15:19:42.121 XML[8388:20b] Stack: (
    807902715,
)

Comment: You need to call UIImage image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"]]]];

Comment: when i tried this code, it passing null into image!!        2011-03-14 15:23:50.999 XML[8447:20b] image....(null)
2011-03-14 15:23:51.000 XML[8447:20b] width.....0.000000,height.....0.000000

Comment: Can you try the + (id)dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)aURL options:(NSDataReadingOptions)mask error:(NSError **)errorPtr to see if there was an error fetching the data from the URL?

Comment: If you're on an iOS version smaller than 4.0 you have to use NSUncachedRead instead.

Comment: ok!! its giving exception in gdb :        -[NSCFString isFileURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3d678c0'

Comment: As everybody told you, you need to put in an instance of NSURL not NSString.

Comment: error release will throw an exception in the above code

Answer (score 9):

The method `dataWithContentsOfURL` take a `NSURL` as argument not a `NSString`

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Images/thunderstorms.gif"]]
```