# dataWithContentsOfMappedFile deprecated in iOS 8.0

Tags: ios, json, swift

I use the following code to retrieve data from JSON file.

```
let jsonData = try NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile("/Users/User/Desktop/Employee.json")
```

I get the following error

```
dataWithContentsOfMappedFile was deprecated in iOS 8.0: Use +dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error: and NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe or NSDataReadingMappedAlways instead
```

Can someone please let me know the alternative?

Comment: Don't you have a solution suggested as well ? `Use +dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error: and NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe or NSDataReadingMappedAlways instead` Have you tried it?

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296002/nsdata-datawithcontentsofurl

Comment: @NeverHopeless I don't want to use it from any url. File is in my local

Comment: Really, it's right there in the header file. _All_ deprecated methods have a line right ther in the header file that tells you what to use instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

for fetch from local path use `contentsOfFile` else use `contentsOfURL`

```
 let contents: NSData?
    do {
        contents = try NSData(contentsOfFile: "/Users/User/Desktop/Employee.json", options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedAlways)
    } catch _ {
        contents = nil
    }

    print(contents)
```

if you want to only access the `contentsOfFile` use the following line

```
    let contents   =  NSData(contentsOfFile:"/Users/User/Desktop/Employee.json")
     print(contents)
```

Comment: I am getting this error

**/Users/Rini/Documents/workspace/MyAppSwift/MyAppSwift/ViewController.swift:20:98: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context**

Comment: I am able to use only this
`let jsonData = try NSData(contentsOfFile: "/Users/User/Desktop/Employee.json")`
But I don't know how to proceed...